# How to add class to ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons parent cell?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How can I add class via cell template to the highest parent div of selection button cell? I need to add extra class name to the div with ui-grid-row class.

I have

```
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd):hover .ui-grid-cell{background:rgb(187,210,157) none repeat scroll 0% 0% }
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even):hover .ui-grid-cell{background:rgb(187,210,157) none repeat scroll 0% 0% }
```

in my css file, and I do not want to hover selection button cells.

```
<div ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)" class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}">
    <div row-render-index="rowRenderIndex" ui-grid-row="row" role="row" class="ng-isolate-scope">
            <!-- ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
                <div ui-grid-cell="" role="rowheader" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0005 ui-grid-row-header-cell" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" id="1444720102515-7-uiGrid-0005-cell">
                        <div class="ui-grid-disable-selection ng-scope">
                                <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
                                        <div ng-click="selectButtonClick(row, $event)" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope">
                                               &nbsp;
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, it's solved,
just I add selector to my css file

```
.ui-grid-render-container-body  .ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd):hover .ui-grid-cell{background:rgb(187,210,157) none repeat scroll 0% 0% }
.ui-grid-render-container-body  .ui-grid-row:nth-child(even):hover .ui-grid-cell {background:rgb(187,210,157) none repeat scroll 0% 0% }
```